Boundedness in $L^p$ and convergence in $L^1$ implies weak convergence in $L^p$
Let $p\in(1,\infty)$ and $f_n$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^p(E)\cap\mathcal{L}^1(E)$ such that $\lVert f_n\rVert_p\leq1$ for every $n$ and there exist $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(E)$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $\mathcal{L}^1(E)$ norm.
Prove that $f\in\mathcal{L}^p(E)$ and that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $\mathcal{L}^p(E)$.
I don't know how to prove either, assuming $f\in\mathcal{L}^p(E)$ i have proved that $f_n\to f$ in $\mathcal{L}^r(E)$ norm for $r\in(1,p)$ using Holder inequality, maybe this is useful. I also know that strong convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1(E)$ norm, implies the existence of a subsequence converging pointwise a.e., but can't think how to use this fact.
(I'm working with the Lebesgue measure, $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ measurable.)

Extraction of an almost everywhere convergent subsequence is a good idea: apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence $\left(\lvert f_n\rvert^p\right)$ to conclude that $f\in\mathcal L^p(E)$.
From the fact that $\lVert f_n\rVert_p\leqslant 1$, we know that there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ and a function $g$ such that $f_{n_k}\to g$ weakly in $\mathcal L^p(E)$.  From the convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ in $\mathcal L^1$, we know that for each measurable set $A$ of finite measure, $\int_A f_n\to \int_Af$. Using the weak convergence $f_{n_k}\to g$, we also get that $\int_A f_{n_k}\to \int_Ag$ hence $f$ and $g$ coincide.
We have shown that there exists a subsequence that converges weakly to $f$. Actually, applying the result to an arbitrary subsequence of $(f_n)$ shows that $f_n\to f$ weakly.
